# Random 3-4 long strings in a http response pythyon

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, https, get

I am trying to make a request with the socket module in python. It successfully makes the request, gets the response, and decodes it. When I am looking at the HTML document it is all correct except there are random 3-4 long random strings in the HTML document. I think I have the code right but I am not 100% sure. Here is my code:

```py
def recive_data(get, timeout):
  ready = select.select([get], [], [], timeout)
  if ready[0]:
    return get.recv(4096)
  return b""

def get_file(website, port, file, https=False):
  data = []
  new_data = ""

  if https:
    get = ssl.create_default_context().wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM), server_hostname=website)
  else:
    get = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  get.connect((website, port))
  get.sendall(f"GET {file} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {website}:{port}\r\n\r\n".encode())
  while True:
    new_data = recive_data(get, 5).decode()
    if new_data != "" and new_data != None:
      data.append(new_data)
      new_data = ""
    else:
      break

  data = "".join(data)
  header = data[0:data.find(newline+newline)]
  data = data[data.find(newline+newline):data.rfind(f"{newline}0{newline}{newline}")]

  data = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser').prettify()

  get.close()
  return (header, data)
```

If I put in https://stackoverflow.com it outputs:

```html
30d
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav">
 <head>
  <title>
   Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers
  </title>
  <link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" rel="shortcut icon"/>
  <link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
  <link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" rel="image_src"/>
  <link href="/opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="Stack Overflow" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
  <meta content="Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online communi
20d0
ty for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers." name="description"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type">
```

*etc...*
However, some website has it more than others and I can't figure that out either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the header in the respones gives you a clue:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: private
...
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

That `transfer-encoding` means what follows the header isn't pure HTML.  From [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

```
   The chunked encoding modifies the body of a message in order to
   transfer it as a series of chunks, each with its own size indicator,
   followed by an OPTIONAL trailer containing entity-header fields
...
   The chunk-size field is a string of hex digits indicating the size of
   the chunk. The chunked encoding is ended by any chunk whose size is
   zero, followed by the trailer, which is terminated by an empty line.
```

In other words, what you're seeing is a hex number showing the number of bytes in the next chunk.  There may be more than one chunk.  You'll need to check for that HTTP header, and if it's present, find all of the chunks and connect them together before parsing the page as HTML.